# How to create and populate structure like below by using for loop? ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, populate

**    Could somebody help me to understand this type of initialization? It seems to me that this part of code:

`"username: @"Johny"` look like  nsdictionary initializationa object for key?**

```
 NSArray *items = @[@{@"username": @"Johny",
                    @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo1.jpg"},

                   @{@"username": @"George",
                     @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo2.jpg"},

                   @{@"username": @"Mandy",
                     @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo3.jpg"},

                   @{@"username": @"Jacob",
                     @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo4.jpg"},

                   @{@"username": @"Brandon",
                     @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo5.jpg"},

                   @{@"username": @"Dave",
                     @"userpic": @"Photo.png",
                     @"image": @"photo6.jpg"}
                   ];
```

**in my code i'm getting all values by using for loop
**

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in items) {
{
    //

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some changes introduced to Objective-C by Apple at the 2012 WWDC. If you have not seen the WWDC 2012 video `Modern Objective-C` then I would highly recommend you viewing that video which explains the changes introduced. Amongst those changes added were `Array Literals` and `Dictionary Literals`

Basically just like you can create a `String Literal` by creating the following:

```
NSString *name = @"Slim Shady"
```

Apple introduced `Array Literals` and `Dictionary Literals` too Following examples are from the Video

Where initially to create an Array the options were:

```
NSArray *myArray; 
myArray = [NSArray array];  // an empty Array
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:anObject];  // an array with a single object
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: a, b, n, nil];  // array with 3 objects a, b, c
```

Array Literals allows you to create an Array in the following ways:

```
myArray = @[ ];   // an empty Array
myArray = @[anObject];  // array with a single object
myArray = @[a, b, c];  // array with 3 objects a, b, c
```

as you can see using the Literals it is clearer and easier to create the Array. Similarly for `NSDictionary`
Where initially the options to create a Dictionary were:

```
NSDictionary *myDict; 
myDict = [NSDictionary dictionary]; // empty Dcitionary
myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:object forKey:key]; 
myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: object1, key1, object2, key2, nil];
```

Dictionary Literals allow you to create the dictionary in the following ways:

```
myDict = @{ }; // empty ditionary
myDict = @{ key:object }; // notice the order of the key first -> key : object
myDict = @{ key1:object1 , key2:object2 };
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an array of dictionary objects using the new(ish) [Objective-C literals syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

As well as the traditional literal strings, which we all know and love: `@"Hello World"`, there are:

- `NSArray` literals:  `@[ element1, element2 ]`, which has the advantage of not needing a trailing `nil` like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` does.
- `NSDictionary` literals: `@{ key : value, key : value }`, which has the advantage of being more natural in the key-value order compared to `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:]`.
- `NSNumber` literals: `@(YES)` (boolean), `@(1.2)` (floating point), `@(123)` (integer).

and they all have the advantage of being much more concise and natural.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6, Apple created a new way of initialising `NSArray` and that's what is the case here.

It functions just like the `arrayWithObjects` functions, just that the syntax is a little different.

Your `NSArray` is filled with `NSDictionary` objects.